# How to make Ghidra don't brake mid token with triple dots?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, ghidra

So I was scraping the Ghidra disassembly output until I realized that some of my tokens are ...

Anyone knows how can I configure this up so Ghidra doesn't limit the output of it's disassembler (especially when outputting Ascii files)?

Comment: Can you post the code you were using for this?                                                                                  I assume you are talking about a script, and not the GUI cutting of long lines in the disassembly listing

Comment: @FlorianMagin The GUI and the export option Ascii

Answer (score 1):

In the export dialog menu there is an `Options...` button that will let you adjust the length of the various fields included in the ascii export. You can increase the length of the fields that you're seeing get truncated so that the entire contents can fit. This might make the document a little harder to read in an editor since you might have to scroll horizontally, but if you're scraping the output then perhaps this won't bother you.